# Create a logical vector in R and use which function

Tags: r

I have a dataset with three columns. The first column is type, second column is area and third column is worth. I want to write a logical vector such that the type =1 , area = 3 and worth = 6. I was able to create the data frame using subset but I couldn't create a logical vector.

```
hello <- read.csv("type.csv")
hello1 <- subset(hello, type==1 & area ==3 & worth ==6)
```

There are many NA values in worth column.
The data set is https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjjwmnr8uxmy18y/type.csv

Thanks.

Jdbaba

Comment: try: `with(hello, hello[type == 1 & area == 3 & worth == 6, ])`

Comment: @ Tyler, thanks for your reply. Actually what I need to do is to assign a logical vector that identifies that type==1 , area ==3 and worth ==6 . After that i need to apply which() function to identify the rows of data frame when the logical vector is true.

Comment: `which(with(hello, type == 1 & area == 3 & Worth == 6))`

Comment: Using stack overflow to do your homework?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So the question remains answered:

```
which(with(hello, type == 1 & area == 3 & Worth == 6))
```

Remember, you can just use it as:

```
which(hello$type1 == 1 & hello$area == 3 & hello$Worth == 6)
```

as well. However, when you have more statements to check for, a `with` comes in handy as it allows you to check without typing `hello$` every time.

Comment: Yes, it is answered. Thanks.

Comment: If like the OP suggests the vector is going to be used for indexing, then you don't need `which`. In fact, it is even recommended not to use it; I have at least one example in mind where it can lead to trouble and it is negative indexing: `hello[-which(bool.vec), ]` is not the same as `hello[!bool.vec, ]` when `bool.vec` is `FALSE` everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Although an answer has already been accepted, the OP asked to create a logical vector, and the answer

```
which(hello$type1 == 1 & hello$area == 3 & hello$Worth == 6)
```

returns the rows which match these conditions.  To instead return a logical vector, simply use the argument to `which`, i.e.

```
hello$type1 == 1 & hello$area == 3 & hello$Worth == 6
```